# Bad resources path in ASP.NET MVC5 page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is curious.

When I have this, for example, in my BundleConfig class:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/iCheck/css").Include(
                "~/Content/iCheck/flat/green.css"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/iCheck/js").Include(
                "~/Scripts/icheck.js"));
```

In a server, resources are retrieved from the correct location:

```
/Content/iCheck/flat/green.css
```

however, in other server, resources are retrieved using this URL:

```
/iCheck/css?v=ENsQ8JbHO7Zzp1Za0G2FBDKGGsGf_VDHd_S5fgCyCxA1
```

That causes images inside the CSS not to be found. How can I solve it? in both servers there is the same deployed version of the site. I don't understand why in one server the bundles behave different from others.

Comment: One is bundled and the other isn't. Are you deploying to each server with different `debug` settings (true/false)? This could be because of building/publishing in Debug/Release mode or different web.config transforms.

Comment: No... both are the same deployed version..... in Release build

Answer (score 0):

Bundling is enabled for Release builds but not for Debug.

The property [BundleTable.EnableOptimizations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundletable.enableoptimizations(v=vs.110).aspx) will allow you to override the bundling setting in development.

To fix the relative paths within the CSS look at the [CssRewriteUrlTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.cssrewriteurltransform(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
.Include("~/Content/iCheck/flat/green.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
```

Comment: The server where bundled was not enabled wwas deploed using Release bukld: 2>------ Publish started: Project: Emergencia, Configuration: Release x64 ------
2>Connecting to C:\WorkingFolder\Proyectos\Lipigas\Web 2.0\Monitoreo de Atenciones\Deploy_x64\Monitoreo...
2>Transformed Web.config using C:\WorkingFolder\Proyectos\Lipigas\Web 2.0\Monitoreo de Atenciones\Monitoreo\Emergencia\Web.Release.config into obj\x64\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
2>Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:

Comment: If you use a bundle then `/iCheck/css?v=ENsQ8JbHO7Zzp1Za0G2FBDKGGsGf_VDHd_S5fgCyCxA1` is the correct location with Bundling enabled, multiple files are combined and minified to a single resource. To fix the relative paths in the bundled CSS use `CssRewriteUrlTransform`. I assume you have multiple files for the bundle otherwise you're really just getting the minification benefit. There is no point in only having one file in the bundle especially if you expect to use the same path `/Content/iCheck/flat/green.css` in your views. What tool is showing you where the resources are retrieved from?

Comment: Firebug is showing the actual path where the resources are being gotten..... if inside CSS, there is a url instruction referring to an image, how can I use CssRewriteUrlTransform to translate the URLs? However, the most curious thing is: if I have published the site (of course, in Release build), and copied exacly the same published files in 2 different servers. Why in one server, resources are minified while in other server they are not?

Comment: I have used new CssRewriteUrlTransform() in the CSS bundle but now the full image path does not contains the virtual directory

Comment: What is building your site code? The answer I've given includes the code for using `CssRewriteUrlTransform `, see also [Relative Paths and the Web Optimization Framework](http://www.seankenny.me/blog/2013/09/04/404-with-relative-paths-and-the-web-optimization-framework/). If you get that working it won't matter if you use the minified bundle or the bundles renders all the css files. Maybe read [Bundling and Minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#additional-resources)